# how to start activiti on click of command button in jsf

Tags: jsf, activiti, bpmn

I am new to activiti . I have a web application where vacation request will be submitted by a employee to his manager. So a form with name and manger and vacation start date and end date will be specified. I have designed the form in jsf . on click of submit button form should be submitted to manager. If manager log in in his work queue he should see the form. I have the bpm and in activiti explorer i have verified the flow. Now how can I integrate the same in my web application running in tomcat

Comment: No code. No code. No code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

Using de java API, see the RuntimeService and the method    startProcessInstanceByKey [RuntimeService](http://activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/RuntimeService.html)
This executes the process in your application context.

You can also use the REST API to execute the process in a remote server.